# If I have 3 batteries 100mAh 200mAh and 300mAh what the total charge in series?

Tags: batteries, capacitance

I have a tiny questions about the total charge the 3 batteries (E=1,5V) in series.

I compute that way:

\$ Qtotal = C_{eq}\cdot 3E\$

\$1/C_{eq} = 1/C1 + 1/C2 + 1/C3\$

\$1/C_{eq} = \frac{(C1C2+C1C3+C2C3)}{C1C2C3}\$

\$C_{eq} = C1C2C3/(C1C2+C1C3+C2C3)\$

\$C_{eq} = Q1Q2Q3/E^3/(Q1Q2+Q1Q3+Q2Q3)/E^2\$

\$C_{eq} = Q1Q2Q3/E\cdot (Q1Q2+Q1Q3+Q2Q3)\$

\$Qtotal = 3\cdot Q1Q2Q3/(Q1Q2+Q1Q3+Q2Q3)\$

\$Qtotal = 3\cdot 100\cdot 200 \cdot 300/(100 \cdot 200+100 \cdot 300+200\cdot 300)\$

\$Qtotal = 3\cdot 100\cdot2\cdot3/11 = 1800/11 = 163.63mAh\$

But seems its not right because the weakest batterieshas the 100mAh.

What am I miss?

Comment: A chain is only as strong as the weakest link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never put batteries of different capacity in series.

In your example, when you start with fully charged batteries, and your system has drawn about 100mAh, your system will likely continue to draw current.  At that point you're going to reversely charge the 100mAh battery which is not good for any battery!  Physical damage is to be expected.

You can't rely on (dis)charging only 100mAh because your 200mAh and 300mAh would get fully charged at some point anyway (trickle charging, etc).

If you were using capacitors, your voltage would not be as stable as with batteries.  when drawing a constant current from a capacitor, your voltages drop lineary, while with a battery it drops slightly over time and drops heavily near its end of charge.

Note: you can put batteries of a different capacity in series, but only do so if you are going to do that for a short period of time and within there limits - for example when you do not have enough batteries and you need to power a device to resolve a very short term situation or do a short test.

Comment: the main current stopped when the weakest batteries "died"?

Comment: @miguel747 it depends on the battery chemistry.  At least with NiMH and NiCd cells, the weakest battery gets completely discharged, then starts charging in reverse which damages the cell.  With LiPo, the cell is damaged long before it ceases to be capable of discharge.  I'm not sure what happens with other chemistries, but it's never good.

Comment: @miguel747 Whether the main current stops or not depends on the load.  If the load does no longer draw any current when the voltage is below a certain level, then the current "stops".  If you use a resistive load, the current will stop only when the net voltage is 0 which will likely mean that two batteries are "reversed" and one still in normal but near empty operation.  Something that you want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring one key fact: You can't charge a battery in reverse! In other words, you can't treat them like capacitors.

This means that a series string is going to be limited to the capacity of the smallest cell (100 mAh), and the excess capacity of the other cells is simply not used.

Comment: Well, you *can* charge a battery in reverse, but it destroys the battery. Though I think some chemistries like lead-acid might be able to survive it?

Comment: @Hearth: The problem is that the cell impedance goes way up at zero charge (for most chemistries), so you can't actually get to the reverse-charged state before everything simply stops working.